# Facebook Like a post using post id

Tags: android, facebook

I created a post on Facebook and received post id. Now I want to create a [like button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) with URL to my post, so when clicking Like the user will like his post.

Is it possible? And how do I JavaScript it or using Android-Facebook sdk3?

Answer (score 1):

You can like a post by issuing a `HTTP` `POST` request to `POST_ID/likes` connection assuming you have `publish_stream` permission.

with `javascript sdk`, you can do something like

```
FB.api("/POST_ID/likes", 'post',function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('successfully, liked the post!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike webpages, you cannot add a Facebook **Like** button to an Android app. I am not sure if this can be done in a `WebView`. However, you can add the function to Like a post by using "POST" or a "DELETE" query to the Facebook API:

Here is a functioning example of what I do to *Toggle* the Like Status of a Post in my application:

**NOTE: This code is for the older v2.x SDK. So you will need to adapt a few things that are specific to the latest v3.x SDK**

On the onClickListener you will use to post / remove a Like, run this piece of code:

```
try {
    String query = "SELECT user_likes FROM stream WHERE post_id= \'"
            + THE_POST_ID + "\'";
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("method", "fql.query");
    params.putString("query", query);
    String fqlResponse = Utility.mFacebook.request(params);

    JSONArray JALikes = new JSONArray(fqlResponse);

    for (int j = 0; j < JALikes.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject JOTemp = JALikes.getJSONObject(j);

        if (JOTemp.has("user_likes"))   {
            String userLikeStatus = JOTemp.getString("user_likes");
            if (userLikeStatus.equals("true"))  {

                try {
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    Utility.mFacebook.request("POST_ID/likes", parameters, "DELETE");

                    // SHOW THE "LIKE" IS REMOVED
                }
                catch(Exception e)  {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (userLikeStatus.equals("false")) {
                try {
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    Utility.mFacebook.request("POST_ID/likes", parameters, "POST");

                    // SHOW THAT THE POST IS NOW "LIKED"
                }
                catch(Exception e)  {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In the first part of the code (**before the `for loop`**), I check the current status if the Logged in user likes the Post. Based on the result (**in the `for loop`**), I either remove the Like or I post a Like.

Although it is an older SDK, the code is still valid, and with a few modifications (if necessary) will work just fine.